# How to lift an "answer ban" / why banned at all?

Tags: support, answers, down-votes

I am new to this Stack, though I have been participating in other stacks before. I answered a couple of question but have got constantly bad reactions, which for some reason are not very well liked.

1. In [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/186811/is-it-academic-dishonesty-if-i-committed-my-exam-answers-into-a-private-github-r/186896#186896) questions I gave an answer, which was tagged "unclear". I don't see that and even another commenter did not see that.
2. In [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/186988/are-there-any-international-standards-laws-or-governing-bodies-that-deal-with/187285#187285) query I give an answer based on my expert knowledge, which seems to be somewhat not acceptable for others.
3. In [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/186887/advisor-is-using-my-ideas-as-grant-proposal/186895#186895) query that is content-wise correct, even though others disagree if my suggestion is smart.

As a consequence I am banned from answering, which paralyzes me on this platform. My take on this platform is: I participate in Academia stack because I am science manager. I have a PhD, I worked at different academic institutions. Since my PhD is on copyright policy, I have some good knowledge about it. I can contribute with answers and suggestions, but not with questions. So my question is

1. How to unban myself?
2. How to prevent from being banned again?

Overall, I am wondering, whether the modus of right/wrong is suitable for most of the questions asked on this platform, because the questions seem to be very often rather vague, which makes answer suggestions.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans

Comment: Thank you for the link. Since I am banned from answering and banned from posting comments, my only way - it seems - is to ask questions.

Answer (score 9):

See [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/401068) which answers your questions about how this happened and how to undo it.

This is an automated system and we cannot intervene to override it.

The specific algorithm is a secret to make the system more difficult to abuse, but in general you get an answer ban when you receive mostly downvotes and few upvotes across multiple posts, including deleted ones.

Although you say you are an expert in some aspects of copyright, it seems all of the answers you link were likely downvoted for confusing plagiarism and other academic ethics concepts with copyright, which are separate concepts that are nonetheless often confused, and I think that makes people fairly aggressive about emphasizing when they are incorrectly interchanged.

Comment: Thank you! My take-away is: don't make people aggressive (and learn about what makes the community here aggressive).

Comment: @slinel Another possible takeaway: copyright law does not govern every legal or ethical issue encountered in academia.

Comment: If you suggest that I should take that away, I am beginning to wonder whether it is a language problem (as I am not a native english speaker). You are refering to example number 2, which was about scientific misconduct and plagiarism. My answer was only about plagiarism, not misconduct. All the critic to my post was about plagiarism. If you'll want to discuss the correctness of my answer, I must be allowed to comment - which I am not. Which is why I am asking what to do about it.

Answer (score 4):

> I am wondering, whether the modus of right/wrong is suitable for most of the questions asked on this platform, because the questions seem to be very often rather vague, which makes answer suggestions.

In that case, you should refrain from answering the question.  If you had sufficient reputation, you could vote to close the question using the "opinion" reason.